# Doctrine date in save override / before save

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, save

I have Doctrine model with a date field "date_of_birth" (symfony form date) which is filled in by the user all works 100% it saves to the db as expected, however in the model save() method I need to retrieve the value of this field before save occurs. My problem is that When trying to get the date value it returns empty string if its a new record and the old value if it is an existing record

```
public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
{
      $dob = $this->getDateOfBirth(); // returns empty str if new and old value if existing
      $dob = $this->date_of_birth; //also returns empty str

      return parent::save($conn);
 }
```

How Can I retrieve the value of this field beore data is saved

Answer (score 7):

In Doctrine 1.2 you can override [preSave](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1-documentation/blob/master/manual/en/event-listeners.txt) pseudo-event:

```
// In your model class
public function preSave($event) {
   $dob = $this->getDateOfBirth();

   //do whatever you need

   parent::preSave($event);
}
```

[In Doctrine 2.1 the function names changed.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#prepersist)

Comment: Links broken... :/

Comment: Also Carlos there is no need to downvote on me because Doctrine Project did not maintain their links throughout the years (6 and a half years now)

Answer (score 2):

Generaly pseudo-events in doctrine uses "new" values, however there is getModified() method and it doing exactly what you need.

```
$modifiedFields = $this->getModified(true);
if(isset($modifiedFields['date_of_birth'])) { //index is available only after change
  echo $modifiedFields['date_of_birth']; //old value
}
```

[more info from doc about getModified()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_record.html#getModified%28%29)